# query about session time out value

Tags: jsp

I am developing a web project using JSP & JAVA. I have to set the **session time out as infinity**. 
The session should expire only when the user's browser is closed.
how can I do it?

I need your suggestion whether it is a good practice to set session time out as infinty. Please provide your opinions.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the session timeout in your web.xml file by adding these lines in your web.xml

```
<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

The value is in minutes, and it is an inactive period, meaning it will be refreshed whenever the browser interacts with the server.

Having an infinite value (don't know if possible) it is highly not recommended. You cannot be sure when the browser closes, and at the end you may run out of memory or have tons of useless sessions stored.

Instead, you may try to have some meta refresh in your html or some ajax request, to keep session alive, though I wouldn't recommend it. Just put a high value in the timeout.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default session timeout specified in Servlet specification,it is left out to the container.

For tomcat it is 30mins.One can always override this value either though DD ?

```
<session-config> 
<session-timeout>600</session-timeout> 
</session-config>
```

or

programmatically by `setMaxInactiveInterval()` method on HttpSession  object .

If the **session timeout is set to -1 the session lifetime extends to infinity** i.e. as long as the container is running.

Finally if application is having session time out is infinity, your session will never expires so it is not good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code snippet in your jsp to hit a js function which will call an ajax function to hit server side component. Then simply use the session API to invalidate the session.

```
window.onbeforeunload = WindowClose; 

function WindowClose() { 

  //Write a AJAx request here to hit the server side servlet of any filter 

}
```

Or use

```
<body onunload="WindowClose(); >
```

In the server side code , use

```
HttpSession session = request.getsession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(0); //or session.invalidate();
```

Also as suggested , it will be good approach to define default session timeout value in the web.xml so that incase browser crashes, sessions will invalidate after the stipulated amount of time has passed.

Comment: I have had lots of problems using the onBeforeUnload event, depending on the browser, or the action that is hit. (it may be called when navigating to another page inside the same site). Also, in the case that the browser crashes, the javascript won't be executed and you'll have the session forever in your server.

Comment: My answer was in addition to your answer. How about 'code'<body onunload="WindowClose();"> 'code' @Pradeep needs a way to invalidate the session based on browser close. i.e he does not want the session to sit on the server for even a single minute more when the user closes the browser window. I agree that we should set the default session timeout configuration in the web.xml as a safety net and as a good practice.